using statemanager in getserversideprops
I am using Next.JS
and I need to store an id somewhere and use it in getServerSideProps of another page.
I don't want to use cookie
what can I use? is there any statemanager I can use in getServerSideProps?
I tried cookie(and saving them with api route) and there are some unexpected conditions which I have to add that it works properly! so i am searching for another way
